# QT QML. Почему на iOS не работает встроенный Material Style?

Tags: qt, ios, qml

Может кто сталкивался? QT 5.11. Не работает встроенный стиль QT Material при сборке приложения под iOS и запуске его в эмуляторе iOS 11.3 (на реальном девайсе не проверял). Раньше вроде было все в порядке, да и в App Store видел QML-приложения с использованием Material. Так-же в доке указано, что этот стиль 100% кросс-платформенный:

> The Material style is a 100% cross-platform Qt Quick Controls 2 style implementation that follows the Google Material Design Guidelines. The style runs on any platform, and looks more or less identical everywhere. Minor differences may occur due to differences in available system fonts and font rendering engines.

В qtquickcontrols2.conf:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark
```

Различия, как говорится, на лицо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]